# What is the main difference between ionic 3 and ionic 4

Tags: ionic3, ionic4

I know **ionic 3** and about to start a new project app in ionic.so whether i should continue with **ionic 3** or i can go with **ionic 4**.if i will go with **ionic 4** then what feature i can get more than **ionic 3**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some differences that I remember:

## Ionic 3:

- Based on Angular 2
- Have own file structure and style guide
- Don't use Angular CLI
- Uses own routing system

## Ionic 4:

- Based on Angular 7 (and should support Angular 8 soon)
- Follows [Angular style guide](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide) for file structure and coding style
- Uses Angular CLI
- Uses Angular Router

You can see the release article on Ionic Blog: https://ionicframework.com/blog/introducing-ionic-4-ionic-for-everyone/

## My opinion about Ionic

IMO, the main difference is that Ionic 3 is abandoned (and it was abandoned almost one year from Ionic 4 release), and have a lot of bugs.

The last release of Ionic 3 was on 8/Nov/2017 while 4.0 was released on 23/Jan/2019, more then a year without updates.

This shows that Ionic Team don't care about it. A lot of developers like me had to workaround a lot of bugs for this period, and rewrite the whole code for 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

Ionic 4 employs more of the Angular Tools, including life cycle events, routing, and loading. I've been using it for over a year and have migrated several apps from Ionic 3. Go with Ionic 4. You won't be disappointed! PS.. Take advantage of the new bells and whistles like the progress bar and skeleton text =)